# Generating migration scripts after upgrading django and moving from mysql to postgres

Tags: django, django-migrations

We have a django app that is running in production.
It used to run django 1.4.3 against a mysql database.
We had all our migration scripts using django south.

We recently upgraded to django 1.11.6. Along with it we moved the data to a postgres database.

The app runs fine, but the migration scripts that are generated using django migrations by using the django models are not fully consistent with the existing schema.

Almost all of the differences seem to be in the index names that are generated.

What are our options to make the django migrations and the database consistent? How do we go forward with this?

Should we generate a new empty database using the django migrations, and migrate the data from the old to the new empty database?

I know we can edit the models.py and set the index names manually but that is too cumbersome, we need to edit hundreds of models; is there an easy way to do that?

Is there a way I can generate the migration scripts from the existing database, and verify if the models are compatible?

Comment: Are all the indexes created with the django ORM? Using model Meta class og coded in the migration files? It seems like a good idea to create new migration files, since South now is merged into django, and there's probably a bunch of improvements since django 1.4

Comment: A possible approach is to use django management commands `dumpdata` and `loaddata` to migrate the model data, and create new migrations using `makemigrations` to deal with index creation. For advanced database features you might have to write some migrations by hand, since mysql and postgresql has different feature sets.